# Chunk ruby on rails text_field name with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, string, split

If I have a rails form that output the following HTML name attribute

```
"recipe[ingredients_attributes][1][quantities_attributes][0][measurement]"
```

How can I split this into chunks with jQuery, so I can manipulate the integers. I would like to avoid the use of a regular expression if possible.

I have a similar function for the rails form helper ID attributes which is as follows

```
function reindexQuantID(existing, parentIndex, index) {
    var str = existing.split('_');
    str[1] = parentIndex;
    str[3] = index;
    return str.join('_');
}
```

This one was easier because the characters are delimited by an _

Comment: Can you give an example of what chunks mean?

Comment: Ideally Id like an array with following elements 'recipe', '[ingredients_attributes]', '[1]', '[quantities_attributes]', '[0]', '[measurement]'

Comment: My end goal is to manipulate the integer values and return a new string

Comment: If you just want the integer values, without a regex you could do `str.split('][')` which will give you `['...', '1', '...', '0', '...']` and you just have to use the elements at positions 1 and 3 in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following uses regex:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\[[a-z0-9_]*\]", "g");
var array = existing.match(regex);
array[1] = "[42]";
array[3] = "[007]";
return array.join("");

# "recipe[ingredients_attributes][42][quantities_attributes][007][measurement]"
```

The array returned by the regex before manipulation is as follows:

```
["recipe[ingredients_attributes]", "[1]", "[quantities_attributes]", "[0]", "[measurement]"]
```

Please note that I'm not very experienced with regex, so there may be a better match, but the code works.

P.S. Just noticed Sparda's comment, that seems to do what you need.